# Fix Video & Power Wire for Security Camera

Tags: security, cctv, ip-camera

Is it possible to fix power & video wires for the security camera shown below? This wire was originally divided into two wires ... one for power (that goes to an adapter) and one for video that goes to DVR. Just thought to ask before giving up on it.[image]

Edit: Added a new picture below to show how the other end of wires look like. Just for illustration only as I don't have actual wires. Only the red and green parts came with camera, as far as I can say.

[image]

Comment: What does the other end look like? Do you have a soldering iron and some heat shrink tubes?

Comment: I added a new picture with some comments. Sorry, don't have the actual wires to take a picture. I don't have soldering iron and heat shrink tubes. But used to work with it years ago.

Comment: You might be able to get with the vendor and get a replacement wire.

Comment: Does the camera support poe ?

Comment: Do you know what the function of each of the wires in that cable is?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

Sure.

Do you have the other end of the cable that was cut off?

- Just strip the wires and solder them back together, matching colors, and insulating each solder joint with heat shrink tubing (that can all be black - you'll see the color sticking out the end of the tube for future identification) then cover the whole kit'n'kaboodle with a big piece of heat shrink tubing to make it reasonably water tight and protect the joints. I'd suggest an added layer of electrical tape, as well around the outside to help stiffen the splice area to protect the solder joints.

You don't have the other end of the cable?

- Contact the manufacturer to order a replacement cable then see above.

Just one note: Those are *extremely* fine wires (18-24AWG, I'd guess) and those are *not* easy to work with. You also don't have much wire sticking out of that base. It *might* be better to open up the base and attach a factory replacement cable directly to the board inside. On the other hand, that might involve desoldering from a PC board inside and resoldering to it which could end up being even more difficult.

If you do go with soldering the individual wires, take your time and use care to *not* break the actual wire once you've stripped them. You don't have much extra to get a 2nd or 3rd chance with.